# Prove or disprove Riemann-integrability (I guess there are uncountably many points of discontinuity)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Consider the function defined by

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x=0\\1, & \textrm{ if }\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor\textrm{ is even}\\-1, & \textrm{ if }\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor\textrm{ is odd}\end{cases}
$$

(Here $\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{k\in\mathbb{Z}: k\leq x\}$ is the floor function.)

Prove or disprove that $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,2]$.

---

My first observation is that
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}0, & x>1\\1, & x=1\end{cases}~\implies f(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\in(1,2]\\-1, & x=1\end{cases}
$$

so on $[1,2]$ $f$ has **finitely many** points of discontinuity and thus Riemann-integrable.

It remains to consider $f$ on $[0,1)$.

There are  **at least countably many points of discontinuity** in $[0,1)$, namely, for example,

$x=\frac{1}{k}, k\geq 2$

since
$$f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\begin{cases}1, & k\geq 2\textrm{ and }k\textrm{ even}\\-1, & k\geq 2\textrm{ and }k\textrm{ odd }\end{cases}$$

But my feeling is that there are even uncountably many points of discontinuity in $[0,1)$ which probably has something to do with the fact that there are uncountably many irrational numbers in $[0,1)$.

Comment: I believe the points of discontinuity are precisely $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\dots\} \cup \{0\}$, which is countable.

Comment: The existence of uncountably many points of discontinuity would not imply (I think) that the function was not Riemann integrable. There are uncountable sets with zero measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a constant on each interval of the type $(\frac 1 n, \frac 1 {n+1})$ and hence it is continuous on each of these.  The only points of dis-continuity are the end points of these intervals which are countable in number. Hence, $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

That function has countably many discontinuity points ($0$ and the points of the form $\frac1n$, with $n\in\Bbb N$). And there is a theorem due to Lebesgue which tells that if the set of points of discontinuity of a bounded function $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable. So, since every countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$, your function is Riemann-integrable.

But you can prove it without usinge that theorem. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since the restriction of $f$ to $\left[\frac\varepsilon4,2\right]$ is Riemann-integrable, there is a partition $P$ of $\left[\frac\varepsilon4,2\right]$ such that $\overline\sum\left(f|_{[0,\varepsilon/4]},P\right)-\underline\sum\left(f|_{[0,\varepsilon/4]},P\right)<\frac\varepsilon2$. Now, let $Q=P\cup\{0\}$. Then $Q$ is a partition of $[0,2]$ and$$\overline\sum(f,Q)=1\times\frac\varepsilon4+\overline\sum(f,P)$$and$$\underline\sum(f,Q)=(-1)\times\frac\varepsilon4+\underline\sum(f,P),$$and therefore\begin{align}\overline\sum(f,P)-\underline\sum(f,P)&=\frac\varepsilon2+\overline\sum\left(f|_{[0,\varepsilon/4]},P\right)-\underline\sum\left(f|_{[0,\varepsilon/4]},P\right)\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}